# Material UI Phone number is messed up when body has dir = 'rtl'

Tags: material-ui, right-to-left

I have a Material UI phone number and when my website is displayed RTL, the phone number aligns itself to the right, but the number also gets messed up. How can I make sure that the number stays as is?

```
  <div open={this.props.open} onClose={this.props.onClose} dir="rtl">
        <DialogTitle title="New User" />
        This text will be RTL led !
        <div>
          <Typography component="label">'Phone Number'</Typography>
          <MuiPhoneNumber
            name="phone"
            data-cy="user-phone"
            defaultCountry={"us"}
            value={this.state.phone}
            value="1(937)-123-4567"
            onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
          />
          <p>614-764-6300</p>{" "}
          {/* number is right aligned but number stays the same which is how it should be*/}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the codesandbox link  https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-phone-number-forked-cczzj?file=/src/CreateUserDialog.js

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior on any HTML input element with `type="tel"`, and that has `dir="rtl"`.

If you want to keep that field left to right you can give it a prop `inputProps={{dir: "ltr"}}` and make the text  aligned to the right with some CSS like `text-align: right;`

Comment: I added input type=tel and it seems to look ok https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-phone-number-forked-cczzj?file=/src/CreateUserDialog.js

Comment: It adds parentheses around 614, and separates it from the others with a space. And in right to left all the words separated with spaces are inverted. I don't really know why it adds that parenthesis, maybe because it's a US phone, which I don't know well. For french numbers it works correctly.